# Force Python to overlap y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have 5 subplots that share an x axis with the y axis alternating right and left. What I am hoping to do (but cant seem to figure out) is how to allow the subplots to overlap one another in order to further reduce the space betweenthe plotted data. I am currently manipulating each subplot by calling each axis (example below)

```
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5) = plt.subplots(5, sharex=True, gridspec_kw=  {'hspace':0}, figsize = (9,12))    
    ax1.scatter(age_1, dD, facecolor='grey')
    ...
    ax2.plot(data,data) 
    ...
```

I am unsure if this is even possible using this subplot method, however, I have been unable to remove the bottom and top 'spines' using another method of creating subplots (example below).

```
plt.figure(sharex=True,figsize=(9,11))
    plt.subplot(5,1,1)
    plt.scatter(age_1, dD, facecolor='grey')
    ...
```

I would love any feedback from someone that has faced this predicament, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to have a negative `hspace`? What's the problem with that? Best provide a runnable example code which shows the issue and use it to explain what you want to have differently.

Comment: Would not it be better to have all the data on the same plot, taking advantage of a secondary Y axis (ax.twinx()) and scaling the data or using a logarithm axis if necessary? I have never seen subplots overlapping each other, but you can probably achieve it by getting the position of the axes and setting a new value. Or maybe use insets?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to let these 5 subplots matching the x-axis while remaining as 5 separated subplots.

So as @Patol75 mentioned in the comment, I think another way you may consider is to put them in one single plot since the data share one common axis.

```
dataSet = [age_1, age_2, age_3, age_4, age_5] # I assume that's the data
colorSet = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'm', 'y'] #or other color
for age, color in zip(dataSet, colorSet):
    plt.scatter(age_1, dD, facecolor = color)
```

If the y-data has too big a magnitude, you could normalize it to gather them together.

Comment: This is how I originally set up the problem but I wasn't able to find a way to change the subplot coordinates within the larger figure. I have since stumbled onto the ax.set_position command which allowed me to manipulate each subplot's position! Thank you, I appreciate your help!